# Tomcat is not detecting index.html page. means default page. showing 404 error

Tags: tomcat

Yes there is a index page under root directory. but it couldn't detecting it. and yes every other applicaion in webapps folder is working fine.

Comment: root directory = `tomcat-home/webapps/ROOT`? Also check `ROOT/WEB-INF/web.xml` `<welcome-file-list>`.

Comment: there is no welcome-file-list tag under ROOT/WEB-INF/web.xml(in win 7) and i also have win xp installed in my system its working fine in xp even though ROOT/WEB-INF/web.xml doesn't have welcome-file-list.

Comment: Is the index page named `index.html`?

Comment: yes it is named as index.html in  ../ROOT folder

Comment: What happens when you add the <Welcome-file-list> to it?

Comment: its not working either

Comment: Had the same problem.  Creating a ROOT folder under tomcat-home/webapps/ and adding index.html worked for me.